# Variable in Snowflake Task

Tags: variables, snowflake-task

I tried to use variable in snowflake task, but I received an error.
I read that task can contain only one statement and I think it can be a reason of failure - after variable setting the must be ';' - wchich means that there are at least two statements: variable declaration and main sql script.
Or maybe I am missing somethin important in documentation?

Is there any way to place variable in Snowflake task?
If not, what is the best workauround for that?

Comment: You can set session parameters [by altering the task](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html#setting-session-parameters-for-tasks).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use multiple statements in the snowflake task, I would suggest using a stored procedure in the task.

> Currently, a task can execute a single SQL statement, including a call to a stored procedure.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html